# Data Transformation in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
ID    MONTHLY_QTY
H1    M1
H1    M2
H1    M3
H1    M4
H2    M1
H2    M4
```

I need to transform it to something like this:

```
ID    col1  col2  col3  col4
H1    M1    M2    M3    M4
H2    M1    M2
```

The number of distinct values of  MONTHLY_QTY are limited i.e M1 - M4.

Is there a way I can achieve this in Python ?

Comment: How are you storing your data, is it a numpy array?

Comment: I am open to anything. right now im using Pandas Dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and if need remove `NaN` [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['g'] = 'col' + (df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='g', values='MONTHLY_QTY')
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (df)
g  col1 col2 col3 col4
ID                    
H1   M1   M2   M3   M4
H2   M1   M4
```

Comment: I think it was typo. If not, OP accept your solution, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this `df`:

```
   ID MONTHLY_QTY
0  H1          M1
1  H1          M2
2  H1          M3
3  H1          M4
4  H2          M1
5  H2          M4

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["MONTHLY_QTY"])
df2     = df.join(dummies)
df2.groupby(['ID' ] )['M1','M2', "M3", "M4" ].sum()

    M1   M2   M3   M4
ID                    
H1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
H2  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

or

```
df2.rename(columns={'M1': 'col1', 'M2': 'col2', 'M3': 'col3','M4': 'col4', })


   col1  col2  col3  col4
ID                        
H1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
H2   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
```

*I couldnt figure out how to replace 1 with column header values.*